# ASP.NET: Can't connect to SQL Server database after uploading to server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to upload my asp.net site to my HostGator windows server. I'm having a problem connecting to the SQL Server database in my `App_Data` folder. It's giving me the error:

> Login failed for user 'PSS004\IWPD_353([UserName])'.

I use Windows Authentication in Visual Studio 2010 to access the database and view the site just fine locally. Is that causing a problem? If so how do I set up a user/pass to use when accessing the database file once it's on my hosting server?

If any further information is needed that I left out just let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run the code from your webserver, its most likely using a network service account (and hence windows auth wont work).  Add a user account to sql server and change the connection string to use sql auth instead and that should fix it

Comment: Ok thanks I'm gonna try this... just gotta find out how to add a user account to the sql server on my hostgator server.

Comment: If your using a shared hosting account its most likely already done for you, you just need to figure out what the account information is.  Might want to place a call/chat to support

Comment: I can't seem to get an answer from HostGator... seems like no one understands what is going on. Is there a method I can use to setup my database so I don't have to change my connectionstring or anything from my local machine (where it is working) to uploading it to their server? -- I changed the connectionstring in web.config and reuploaded it with a specified user id and password but the error still says `Login failed for user 'PSS004\IWPD_353([UserName])'.` So I guess I need to change something somewhere else also as that's not the user id I specified in the connectionstring.

Comment: it looks like on host gator they have a cPanel control panel.. Try logging into that and see if it has the username/pass for your database.